# Optimizer returning None

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to run an AdamOptimizer for one step of training, unsuccesfully.

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    _, cost_value = sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:X_data, Y: Y_data})
```

In the code, cost is a well defined function implementing a conv NN plus a logistic loss function, using two parameters X, Y (the entry of the NN and the training labels respectively)

When I run this, the console is informing me that the run is returning None as an output, which leaves me baffled since I expected it to return me the cost.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think the `optimizer` is going to return anything. `optimizer.minimize` (or the `train_op`) will return an [op](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#minimize) which will used to update the trainable weights and increment the global step.
If you want loss (or cost) returned, then you must [specify](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/mechanics#train_loop) so in `sess.run([..., loss, ...], ...)`

This is what your code may look like:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    _, cost_value = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X:X_data, Y: Y_data})
```